# Extract Tuple values on the fly

Tags: scala, tuples, extract, on-the-fly

Is there a way how I can extract values from a Tuple on the fly?

Let's assume the tuple:

```
val x = ("1", 2, "3")
```

and the method:

```
def doFoo(value1: String, value2: Int, value3: String)={}
```

How can I call *doFoo()* with the tuple 'x'? Something like doFoo(x), and the values in the tuple are extracted on the fly to match the method signature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(doFoo _).tupled(x)
```

or

```
Function.tupled(doFoo _)(x)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I think you have a typo - shouldn't the second solution be Function.tupled(doFoo _)(x) ?

Comment: Thanks, first time I've seen this.

Comment: @hyperboreean, no. When you pass a method name where a function is expected, then if the types conform, the method will be automatically lifted to the required function type. This is called eta expansion.

Comment: I am getting the following error when trying your solution, that's what I said it was a typo: scala> Function.tupled(doFoo)(x)
Function.tupled(doFoo)(x)
<console>:10: error: missing arguments for method doFoo in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       Function.tupled(doFoo)(x)

Comment: @hyperboreean, hmm, that's peculiar. My guess is that compile fails to perform eta expansion because `Function.tupled` is an overloaded method. Thanks for pointing. I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: @missingfaktor this is a powerful solution, can it be applied to case classes? I'm getting a "_ must follow method; cannot follow Foo.type" compile error

Comment: @virtualeyes, if `Foo` has no type parameters, `Function.tupled(Foo)` should work. In a general case, `Function.tupled(Foo.apply _)` should work. Also you might need to help type inferer a bit.

Comment: yeah, I'm working with query results that are a collection of tuples, so the mapping is not as simple as OP's question.  I'll create a new question in awhile to illustrate...